# What kinds of input streams can you call seekg on?

Tags: c++, stream, iostream, seekg

I have a function (legacy) that reads the first few lines of a file to determine its type, then closes and reopens the file so it can re-read the entire file using the correct interpreter.  The gist is:

```
void readFile(const char *filename) {
  ifstream is(filename);
  Filetype ft = determineFileType(is);
  is.close();
  is.open(filename);
  parseFile(is, ft);
}
```

I needed a similar function that can work on an already-opened stream.  I created a new function that takes an `ostream &` instead of a `char *filename` -- basically this:

```
void readFile(istream &is) {
  std::ios::streampos pos = is.tellg();
  Filetype ft = determineFileType(is);
  is.seekg(pos);
  parseFile(is, ft);
}
```

It seems to work when the `istream` is actually a `stringstream` or an `fstream` but I wonder if I'm just getting lucky.  I also did a small test on `seekg`-ing `std::cin` and it worked, which surprised me.

**So my question**: what kinds of streams are you allowed to use `seekg` on?  When will it fail?  Spec references would be great -- I looked through and the stuff on `seekg`, `pubseekpos`, `seekpos`, `seekoff` weren't helpful at all.

I'd like to reimplement the original function in terms of the new (as below), but I just don't know if that's safe.

```
void readFile(const char *filename) {
  ifstream is(filename);
  readFile(is);
  is.close();
}
```

Comment: I think `seekg` is implemented for all input streams, but it may just be a no-op if the stream isn't seekable.

Comment: Right, it's implemented for all `istream`s, but it may fail and set `failbit` I think.  Just wondering if there are any specs on when that may happen -- like, maybe on `fstream` it's guaranteed to work and on `std::cin` it's implementation dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real answer one can give is that it works where it works.  In
the case of `std::stringbuf`, it should work everywhere.  In the case of
`std::filebuf`, whether it works or not depends on the system; it will
generally work if the `filebuf` is opened on an actual file, but will
usually fail (perhaps silently, if the system doesn't report an error)
for many other types of input: from a keyboard, or a named pipe, for
example.

A more robust solution would be to cache the initial input, and re-read it from the cache.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Too bad there's no way to tell what _kind_ of `istream` I have.  I agree about a cache being a better solution.  For the moment though, I'm trying to reduce the chances that I break existing code.  Thanks for the answer!